# Intel MPI library для Fortran в Visual Studio

Tags: mpi

Поставил intel parallel studio XE 18 под VS17, всё нормально интегрировалось кажется, mpi библиотеки видны по крайней мере по адресу:

C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2018.1.041\compilers_and_libraries_2018\windows\mpi\

Дальше попробовал скомпилировать тестовый MPI файл (test.f90), естественно не скомпилировался, оказалось что нужно библиотки подключать в свойствах проекта

Вписал пути для include и в директорию в линкере прописал папку debug ( в дебаге соотвтетсвенно пока ипытаюсь запускать)

Соответственно вот пути:

Additional include directories: C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2018.1.041\compilers_and_libraries_2018\windows\mpi\intel64\include

Additional Library directories: C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2018.1.041\compilers_and_libraries_2018\windows\mpi\intel64\lib\debug

После этого компилироваться стал, а вот при запуске выдаёт уже:

```
1>MPI_FIRST.f90
1>Linking...
1>MPI_FIRST.obj : warning LNK4049: 
1>MPI_FIRST.obj : warning LNK4049: 
1>MPI_FIRST.obj : warning LNK4049: 
1>MPI_FIRST.obj : warning LNK4049: 
1>MPI_FIRST.obj : warning LNK4049: 
1>MPI_FIRST.obj : error LNK2019: 
1>MPI_FIRST.obj : error LNK2019: 
1>MPI_FIRST.obj : error LNK2019: 
1>MPI_FIRST.obj : error LNK2019: 
1>MPI_FIRST.obj : error LNK2019: 
1>MPI_FIRST.obj : error LNK2019: 
1>MPI_FIRST.obj : error LNK2019: 
1>x64\Debug\MPI_FIRST.exe : fatal error LNK1120:
```

Погуглил error LNK2019, говорят вот что: "Эта ошибка может возникать, если файл объекта или библиотеки, который содержит определение символа не включен в сборку", значит проблема именно с подключением библиотеки MPI. Но как её по другому подключать, не знаю. В связи с этим и вопросы

1) Правильно ли подключил Intel MPI library?

2) Если да, то чем вызваны ошибки?

Спасибо!

Comment: с VS не работал, но не вижу, чтобы было описание передачи собственно самой библиотеки линкеру (аналогия ключа -l<lib_name> для gcc).

Comment: Значит вероятнее всего include сработало, а в линкере уже не то что-то?

Comment: да, линкеру надо передать помимо пути к библиотеке её имя.

Comment: аа, всё, заработало! Имя прописал и всё получилось! Спасибо огромное!